# Wagtail Recaptcha Localhost - SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED

Tags: python, django, ssl, wagtail

Let me know if more or different information needs to be provided. I don't want to add too much if it's unnecessary.

I'm trying to incorporate Wagtail recaptcha to a contact me form. I can do the google captcha just fine, but once I hit submit I run into an error. I am currently running into this error: SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED which you can see here https://pastebin.com/4WaqX1xT
In my current setup I'm using `./ngrok 8000`. My wagtail application runs on `localhost:8000`

These are the domains I have on google recaptcha admin panel

```
localhost
whateverlettersgeneratedby.ngrok.io
127.0.0.1
```

In my settings base.py I have this included to my INSTALLED_APPS

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'sslserver',
    'captcha',
    'wagtailcaptcha',
    ...
]
```

That being said, I did try django-sslserver and received the same error. HTTPS was crossed out when I went to the url using HTTPS instead of HTTP.

Also in base.py I am using Google Recaptcha's development keys. Using my actual keys also result in the same error being generated.

```
RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY = '6LeIxAcTAAAAAJcZVRqyHh71UMIEGNQ_MXjiZKhI'
RECAPTCHA_PRIVATE_KEY = '6LeIxAcTAAAAAGG-vFI1TnRWxMZNFuojJ4WifJWe'
NOCAPTCHA = True
RECAPTCHA_USE_SSL = False
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = False
```

Other things I've tried: stunnel, I get a 403 regarding CSRF Verification Failure https://pastebin.com/JXWVWNJq

My stunnel setup was from http://userpath.co/blog/a-simple-way-to-run-https-on-localhost/
Then I did the command below, but HTTPS was crossed out when I tried going to the url using HTTPS.

`HTTPS=on python manage.py runserver`

My Jinja template does use csrf token
https://pastebin.com/meXdkbfC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is an *outgoing* request that is failing SSL verification. Your local setup does not need to run under HTTPS. Try installing a certificate bundle with `pip install certifi` or see these answers ["SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED" Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27835619/ssl-certificate-verify-failed-error)

Comment: Ok, I tried certifi at some point and same error. So if you can help me clarify the solution in that other question, that would be much appreciated. Question: where would the sslcontext code go in this case? Would it be a separate file outside of the project?

Comment: I don't think the accepted answer in the link I posted is the way to go, you can try setting `NOCAPTCHA = False` and 
`RECAPTCHA_USE_SSL = False` See: https://github.com/praekelt/django-recaptcha/blob/develop/captcha/client.py#L98

Comment: Changing NOCAPTCHA = False instead of NOCAPTCHA = True worked. Obviously foregoing the newer version captcha.